# Set a WMS URL in QGIS using project variables

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-variable

I would to know if it is possible to set a WMS url in which I would use project variables as parameters?

Let's say I have:
QGIS project variable : my_variable = some_query
WMS url : https://wxs.myserver.com/wms?LAYERS=OI.OrthoimageCoverage& EXCEPTIONS=text/xml&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0& REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

I want to replace the LAYERS=OI.OrthoimageCoverage with my predefine project variable as follow:

https://wxs.myserver.com/wms?LAYERS=@my_variable& EXCEPTIONS=text/xml&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0& REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do u mean : _"is it possible to build a url **string** using project variables"_ ?

Comment: A string not really. My idea was to have a WMS layer in a project that can be updated following a property stored as project variable. If the variable in the project is modified, then the URL for the WMS layer will be too.
But I don't know if it is possible or not.